# Parse.com storing issue

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform

So I'm trying to implement a feature where you can vote on object in a listview in the same way you can on reddit with a upvote and downvote system. The system I thought would be simple where you press the upvote button and it would increment the total score but I've run into some issues. First issue is when I press upvote the number on the post score does increment but when I refresh the Parse database the number doesn't store. When I restart the app the score doesn't save either so it looks like all that happens is the score on the list increments but doesn't save. Second issue is with decrementing, I tried doing the same thing as I did with incrementing but there doesn't seem to be a function for changing the number the same way incrementing does (that is with increment("PostScore", 1), it only has decrement()). If I just use decrement() I run into a NullPointer Error.

Here is my queryAdapter:

```
    // Set up the query adapter
    postsQueryAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<AnywallPost>(this, factory) {
        @Override
        public View getItemView(final AnywallPost post, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (view == null) {
                view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.anywall_post_item, null);
            }
            //TextView DetailsView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content_view);
            TextView contentView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content_view);
            TextView usernameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.username_view);
            TextView postscoreView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.PostScore);
            RadioButton upvote = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.Upvote);
            RadioButton downvote = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.DownVote);

            //DetailsView.setText(post.getDetails());
            contentView.setText(post.getText());
            usernameView.setText(post.getUser().getUsername());
            postscoreView.setText(post.getInt().toString());
            upvote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    post.increment();
                }
            });
            downvote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //post.decrement();
                }
            });

            return view;
        }
    };
```

here is my getter and setter activity for the posts:

```
package com.binarsunset.topic;

import com.parse.ParseClassName;
import com.parse.ParseGeoPoint;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

/**
 * Data model for a post.
 */
@ParseClassName("Posts")
public class AnywallPost extends ParseObject {

    public void increment() { increment("PostScore", 1);
    saveInBackground();
    }

    public void decrement() { decrement(); }

    public String getText() {
        return getString("text");
    }

    public void setText(String value) {
        put("text", value);
    }

    public ParseUser getUser() {
        return getParseUser("user");
    }

    public void setUser(ParseUser value) {
        put("user", value);
    }

    public ParseGeoPoint getLocation() { return getParseGeoPoint("location"); }

    public void setLocation(ParseGeoPoint value) {
        put("location", value);
    }

    public void setInt(int number){ put("PostScore", number); }

    public Number getInt(){ return getNumber("PostScore"); }

    public String getDetails() {
        return("Details");
    }

    public void setDetails (String value){
        put("Details", value);
    }

    public static ParseQuery<AnywallPost> getQuery() {
        return ParseQuery.getQuery(AnywallPost.class);
    }
}
```

I think the problem might lie in how I am using saveInBackground but I could be very wrong. If there is need for anymore code please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: But i can't your __saveInBackground__ code here

Comment: I'm pretty sure saveInBackground is a parse.com function unless you are talking about my data thats at parse.com?